# Error - Android Studio - Gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

from nowhere the Androis Studio gives me these errors:

Error image:

[image]

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Make sure that you have all the dependencies added to build.gradle. Also, try to post errors as text rather than a screenshot :)

Comment: I have all the dependencies. Thanks for the advice :)